# Constructor in an abstract class use in a derived class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, abstract-class

Let's say that I have the following abstract class:

```
class Animal
{
private:
    string _name;
    int _age;
public:
    Animal(const string name, const int age);
    virtual void eat() = 0;
};
```

If I want to create a new derived class, for example, a Dog class. How do I call Animal's constructor, as Animal is an abstract class?
More than this, if I'd have 2 more classes under Dog: Pug and Poodle (I know that the example isn't that good but let's ignore that). How will those two classes use Animal c'tor?

Comment: you call it in the same way you call a constructor of a non-abstract base class. Did you write some code and encountered a problem? Please post a [mcve] of that code

Comment: I feel kinda lost and I'm not sure where to start. Should I override Animal's constructor's code in Dog? How will the c'tor function if I use it like a non-abstract base class? In a non-abstract base class I can write the constructor's code, but something that I can't really do in an abstract class

Comment: are you confused because you cannot create an instance of an abstract class? You can create an `Animal` as subobject of a derived class, thats no problem. Given the derived implements all pure virtual methods there really is no differnce in calling the constructor of an abstract / non - abstract base class. I suggest you to forget about the "abstract" part of the question for a moment and read the duplicate. If then you still encounter a problem you can show your code